# can you configure a ultrawide monitor to show 2 different input?

Tags: display

I have purchased a ultra wide monitor (LG 34UC79G-B); and it has 2 HDMI and one mini displayport.

Now, I have my main pc connected to one input, and a linux machine on the second, and was wondering if there is any way to have the monitor divided in 2, like if I had 2 separate monitors, so I can use both the linux and windows machine at the same time.

Is there a software that allow this, or is there a way to do this on my monitor? I see that the monitor has a software that allow you to split screen, but I can't figure out how do you assign an input to each "section".

Comment: `monitor has a software` ... do you load it into the monitor?

Comment: use PIP ... i think that might do what you want

Comment: The software install on the OS, not on the monitor itself; from what I can see, it does what W10 does: you can move apps in specific areas of the screen and it does keep it there.
Although I need to use different input; not different apps